# Reopen request: What is the origin of “ex”?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

Can you please reopen:
[What is the origin of "ex"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/295273/what-is-the-origin-of-ex)

The reason for closing it was the following:

> "Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic."

**The research has now been included.** Moreover, the OP didn't *only* ask about the origin of *ex*, but he also wanted to know: *Does ex have a full form?* As a result, the answer is not  easily ‘Googlable’.

The community should reopen the question because, in my opinion, it is a good and valid question.

Note: I don't favor questions without any research at all, but questions should be saved if they have good answers. For example, I wouldn't reopen a question that asks "What is the etymology of book?" and if lacked any details in the question body.

<sub>OK maybe I'm just being too nice in the spirit of the holidays :)</sub>

Comment: I voted to reopen it. I am proud. :-)

Comment: I just did, too.

Comment: If research has been included in the edited answer, it should be reopened.